# var_dump, print_r produces 'Content Encoding Error'

Tags: php, var-dump

i'm trying to debug some code, every time I use var_dump in Chrome I get an error which says 'Content Encoding Error'.

In Opera var_dump almost works as expected, but there is a whole bunch of garbled text and symbols after it. Here's the first part:

```
bool(false) array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "3" } array(2)   { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "3" } ��Y�n��;�x*P����G��^����ޡ��?��@K�͘u$e��F}�>YgHY��8�.
```

I am able to use var_dump on other sites on the same server, all running the same version of PHP and within the same PHP framework.

Does anybody know what could be causing this? The server is running PHP 5.2.17.

Edit - Some more info.

It happens when I try to var_dump anything, for example:

```
$test = 'test';   
var_dump($test);
```

Here's the header encoding details:

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: What data are you trying to send? Show some code?

Comment: you're probably sending unicode data and setting headers for non unicode encoding - or the opposite. what's the data? and what's the encoding headers?

Comment: Looks like there is something else being sent by your code after you do the var_dump(), maybe look down the page for anything else being output?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if I leave out var_dump the code executes as expected. The garbled characters are definitely being caused by the var_dump function. Interestingly it also happens with print_r.

Comment: and what happens if you `exit` just after `var_dump` ?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller it works fine when I exit after var_dump. Does this mean something is going wrong somewhere further down?

Comment: yup, i suppose there is some attempt to buffer output and compress it, so you are receiving var_dump as plain-text and rest of page as gziped content, but without proper header, so that's why it looks like gibberish.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i can work around it using exit() for now.

Comment: Hmm, I rmember seeing this before, a long time ago... But of course, your real problem is that you are using php 5.2, which is far out of date. You really shouldn't be using anything older than 5.4, and even that is really pushing it.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to use force charset on var_dump, I usually type:

```
echo "<meta charset='UTF-8'>";
var_dump($test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can happen if an output buffer is open and a limit reached.
Try:

```
var_dump($anything);
ob_flush();
```